# PHP $_POST weird

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I have issue when sending POST through ajax to PHP.

the server code

```
<?php 
echo file_get_contents('php://input');
print_r($_POST);
exit(0);
?>
```

the ajax request

```
var data = {key: 'value', __appversion: 0, __appos: 'Android'}
jQuery.ajax({
            'url': the_url,
            'method': 'POST',
            'cache': false,
            'dataType': 'json',
            'data': data,
            'error': function (xhr, status, error) {},
            'success': function (data, status, xhr) {}
        });
```

Using chrome's dev console simulating mobile, the request is as below

```
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,id;q=0.6,ms;q=0.4
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:40
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Host: xxxx-censored-xxxx
Origin:http://xxxx-censored-xxxx
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://xxxx-censored-xxxx
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0; SM-G900P Build/LRX21T) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Mobile Safari/537.36

Form Data

key: value
__appversion: 0
__appos: Android
```

And, the result is (the `json` part is I aware)

```
os=Android__appversion=0&__appos=AndroidArray
(
    [os] => Android__appversion=0
    [__appos] => Android
)
```

The question is,
why is the variable submitted to the server is missing? Like the `key` variable, and also `__appversion` is missing.

I'm expecting the `print_r($_POST)` giving `Array('key' => 'value', '__appversion' => 0, '__appos' => 'Android');`

What is I did wrong with the PHP ?
PHP 7.0.20 at WebFaction. Thank you.

Comment: It's not really clear what your question is.

Comment: I don't see any problems with the output.

Comment: I am sending 3 keys to the server, and expecting `Array('key' => 'value', '__appversion' => 0, '__appos' => 'Android');`

Comment: how you are handling ajax coming data? can you show that code?

Comment: i have not perform any javascript to handle the data, because I am currently focusing on data sent by ajax. I am actually confused, because chrome's dev tool shows the data is sent, but I can't retrieve it via PHP's `$_POST`.

Comment: @Lee  when you are printing `echo"<pre/>";print-r($_POST);` simply what it outputs? on your php page do it as very first line and see

Comment: @AlivetoDie this is the output `Array
(
    [os] => Android__appversion=0
    [__appos] => Android
)`

Comment: do like this `var data = {'key': 'value', '__appversion': 0, '__appos': 'Android'}`  and then check

Comment: hi, i did like you said, and yield the same result.